# How to verify certificates for Liveness probe configured to https?

Tags: kubernetes, https, certificate, schema, readinessprobe

I'm using readinessProbe on my container and configured it work on HTTPS with scheme attribute.
My server expects the get the certificates. how can I configure the readiness probe to support HTTPS with certificates exchange? I don't want it to skip the certificates

```
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /eh/heartbeat
          port: 2347
          scheme: HTTPS
        initialDelaySeconds: 210
        periodSeconds: 10
        timeoutSeconds: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Readiness command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) instead of HTTP request. This will give you complete control over the check, including the certificate exchange.

So, instead of:

```
readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /eh/heartbeat
      port: 2347
      scheme: HTTPS
```

, you would have something like:

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - python
    - your_script.py
```

Be sure the script returns 0 if all is well, and non-zero value on failure.
(python your_script.py is, of course, just one example. You would know what is the best approach for you)

Comment: where do I keep the certificates in such case?

Comment: Inside your docker image. The same for the script.

Comment: Actually, you can also pull them from an online location somewhere. When you have the power of the script it's up to you how you will solve any challenge. Point is, almost anything is solvable.

Comment: @DraganBocevski Is there any way to implement it at configuration file level instead of writing different script?